# $A \setminus B$ is infinite, $B$ - finite. Proof that $(A \setminus B) \sim A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A, B$ - sets such that $A \setminus B$ is infinite, $B$ - finite.
Proof that $(A \setminus B) \sim A$

Comment: Could you provide your attempts on this problem?

Comment: I have literally no idea what should I do to solve this problem. I don't understand how some set without a part of it can still be equipollent to itself

Comment: What is the definition of infinite sets you have used?